# Getting stack offsets of variables from debugging symbols

Tags: c, gdb, bfd

When I build a program with debugging information (`gcc -g`), `gdb` is able to tell me addresses of local variables inside a function. Thus, the debugging symbols must contain enough information to calculate this (i.e. an offset from `ebp`), and since `gdb` uses `libbfd` to read debugging symbols, I should be able to as well.

However, `libbdf`'s documentation seems to have nothing on this. Can `libbfd` give me this information?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`libbfd` will provide access to the ELF file, opening the file, getting access to the contents of the section, but interpreting these contents is not something that `libbfd` does, this is something the application would need to do.

Usually, debugging information is encoded using [DWARF](http://www.dwarfstd.org/).

There are libraries for [interpreting DWARF](http://sourceforge.net/projects/libdwarf/) however, gdb includes it's own code for [parsing DWARF](https://sourceware.org/git/gitweb.cgi?p=binutils-gdb.git;a=blob;f=gdb/dwarf2read.c;hb=HEAD).